# Difference between Float32Array and Int32Array

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

What's the difference between this:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new Float32Array(buffer);
view[0] = 1;
```

and this

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new Int32Array(buffer);
view[0] = 1;
```

I'm wondering about the difference between `Float32Array` and `Int32Array`. Do they translate `1` differently into binary representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they do. Assuming little-endianness, the binary representation of an element of `Int32Array` set to the value `1` will have 31 zero bits followed by 1 one bit.

Whereas the corresponding element of a `Float32Array` has the bit pattern `00111111100000000000000000000000`. (The first bit is the sign, the following 8  the *exponent* and the final bits are the *significand*).

Comment: thanks, and the difference between `Int32Array` and `Uint32Array` is that the first will parse as `31 zero bits followed by 1 one bit`, and the second as `all 1's` (two's complement)?

Comment: Uint32Array has exactly the same bit pattern for 1 as Int32Array.

Comment: sorry, I meant negative 1 as in `view[0] = -1;`

Comment: minus one in 2's complement has every bit set to 1.

Comment: Yes, so is this correct? The difference between Uint32Array and Int32Array and  is that the first will parse `-1` as `31 zero bits followed by 1 one bit`, and the second as `all 1's` (two's complement)? The first one just ignores the sign?

Comment: @Maximus: Might I suggest you ask another question for that. In C and C++ (my primary areas of expertise), the program behaviour would be undefined. My understanding in Javascript, is that -1 coerced into an unsigned will set the bit pattern to 32 one bits thus yielding the largest unsigned possible for that type.

Answer (score 1):

A `Float32Array` represents the values as 32-bit float numbers (that is, decimal numbers), while `Int32Array` represents them as 32-bit signed integers.

This example demostrates the differences:

```js
const floatArray = new Float32Array(1);
const intArray = new Int32Array(1);

floatArray[0] = 1.5;
intArray[0]   = 1.5;

console.log(floatArray[0]); // = 1.5
console.log(intArray[0]);   // = 1
```